# Sudo gedit error

Tags: sudo, gedit

```
** (gedit:8315): CRITICAL **: file log.c: line 980: unexpected error: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon exited with status 1 (g-dbus-error-quark, 25)
```

It works alright if I do `gksu gedit`.

Comment: Don't open gui application through `sudo`.

Comment: Use `nano` or `vim` for such tasks.

Answer (score 5):

First you should read this *[Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application/270019#270019)*

But you should be able to start **gedit** using `sudo -H gedit`

While searching I found similar problem reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1245589).

A bug is reported there "*Ubuntu 13.10 "gedit" fails every time unless user removes zeitgeist directory.*"

So running this command

```
rm ~/.local/share/zeitgeist -R
```

seems to solve the issue.

Comment: I confirmed this worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. I was not using "sudo", just trying to lauch `gedit`.

Answer (score 2):

> **gksu**  is a frontend to su and gksudo is a frontend to sudo.  **Their primary purpose is to run graphical commands** that need root without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly.

To open GUI application from terminal use `gksu` or `gksudo` as following:

```
gksudo gedit
```

If `gksu` not installed then first install by `sudo apt-get install gksu`.

---

However It is recommended to run command-line as root and **Don't run GUI apps as root**.